# How to keep a redundant home directory for offline use?

Tags: rsync, nfs, home

Scenario: My home dir is on NFS, identities are in LDAP and authorization is via Kerberos.  My NFS, LDAP and Kerberos servers are all VMs -- I'm stretching a little hardware a long way at home.

Life is Good ... until -- there's always an until -- my VM server down for maintenance (planned or worse) which then strips me of lots of conveniences for the maintenance/repair work.

For clarity here: $HOME and $USER are the normal, real ones while $CHOME and $CUSER are the local clones.

Option 1: rsync -av $HOME/ $CHOME/
Easy, but while sssd will cache my credentials for the offline period $USER points to $HOME (which is inaccessible) and not $CHOME.

Option 2: Similar but make $CHOME owned by $CUSER instead.
Now $USER is denied access to $CHOME or, alternatively $CUSER is denied access $HOME.  I can't use root because $HOME is exported with root_squash and I'd like to keep it that way.

Option 3: Like option 2 but use ACLs somehow.
Shouldn't I be able to setfacl default ACLs on $CHOME before the first rsync and have them survive?  Everything I've tried requires setfacl -R $CHOME again after each rsync and that seems like I'm just doing something wrong.

I really only need the one-way replication, but the best solution would be something like Unison so that this could move beyond a simple recovery/maintenance aid to also support our laptop using NFS while online at home but operating normally while offline.

Comment: Are USER and CUSER actually different numeric userids? They probably don't need to be.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that detail.  I started out with both having the same UID, but then $CUSER from /etc/passswd became dominant over $USER from LDAP.  I didn't want to reorder things is /etc/nsswitch.conf for fear of unleasing new problems.  The more I think about this the more certain I become that there should be no $CUSER and that the best solution would be to do some bind-mount of $CHOME onto $HOME during the auto-mount.  I have systemd at my disposal so maybe there's something I can leverage there.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of variations on your option 2 seem plausible. I'll continue to assume you usually log in with `$USER` on `$HOME`, just like in your scenario. You've stated that you can't copy the files from `$HOME` to `$CHOME` because of permissions issues (`$USER` can't access `$CUSER`), and you can't bypass that with root because of your `root_squash`.

2a. Adjust the permissions for `$USER` and `$CUSER` such that they belong to a common primary group. Set the `umask 002` for both so that they create files with group permissions the same as for the user. Update all files in `$HOME` and `$CHOME` so that the group ownership is this new group. Use `rsync -avH --no-owner [--delete] $HOME/ $CHOME/` to copy changed files. Run a couple of `cron` jobs (one for `$USER` and one for `$CUSER`) to fix up errant permissions and group memberships of all files.

2b. Leave everything "as is", and copy the files from one account to the other using `rsync` from the client to itself, changing identity across the connection: `rsync -avH [--delete] $HOME/ ${CUSER}@localhost:`